# Is there a way to animate the increased size of a View when new children are added?

Tags: react-native, react-animated, react-native-reanimated

I’m currently using `LayoutAnimation` to animate a view when children are added. However, since LayoutAnimation causes *everything* to be animated, globally, and I can’t easily use built-in Animated library to fit my use-case, I’m wondering if react-native-reanimated is able to help.

Here's a snack of my current solution:
https://snack.expo.io/@insats/height-adapation

This is what the result of that looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve the same thing without using `LayoutAnimation`? I've looked through all exampled in react-native-reanimated, and I've read through the docs but I'm still not sure if this is possible to do or how I should get started. I've thought about using `Animated` to move the item-wrapper out of the viewable area and "scroll" it upwards (using transform translateY) when items are added, but that would require fixed height, which I don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have 2 approaches that I can suggest out of my mind:

1. You can configure your `LayoutAnimation` only when your desired state changed. If you use hooks it would be too easy:

   ```
   const [state,setState] = useState([]);
   useEffect(()=>{
      /*rest code*/
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut)
   },[state])
   ```

   Or if you use class component you can catch your desired state change in `componentDidUpdate`:

   ```
   componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
      if(prevState.items!==state.items){
          LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut)
      }
   }
   ```
2. You can use `onLayout` function of view:

   ```
   addItem = () => {
      this.setState({
         items: [...this.state.items, {title:'An item',isNew:true}]
      })
   }; 
   renderItems = () => {
      return this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
         let opacity = new Animated.Value(0);
         return (
           <Animated.View onLayout={({nativeEvent})=>{
              if(this.state.item.isNew){
                 // here you got the height from nativeEvent.layout.height
                 // Then you have to store the height animate height and opacity to its precise value 
                 // PS I used opacity:0 to calculate the height
                }
              }} key={index} style={[styles.item,{opacity}>
             <Text>{item.title}</Text>
           </View>
          )
      });
   };
   ```

When it comes to `react-native-reanimated` I regard it as more faster version of `react-native`'s `Animated` library. So either way you will have to calculate the height!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The first suggestion, with `LayoutAnimation` is basically what I'm already doing, but it creates all kind of weird layout behaviours all over the app. I'm looking at your second approach because I'm quite comfortable to working with `Animated`, but I had no idea about onLayout. In your example, you're animating the  entrance of a single new item, right? But in my case I'd want to animate the height of the list itself, no?

Comment: I knew that you were going to animate the height. Before you animate the height you have to first calculate the height. For this reason first render the item with 0 opacity and when you got the height you will set opacity to 1 and animate the height as indicated in comments!

Comment: Did you mean something like this? https://snack.expo.io/@insats/calm-tortillas

Comment: Yeah exactly but instead of animating opacity after evaluating height  you could interpolate the height! That way it would look much smoother! It is the first time I am ever met the person who thinks exact the same way as me!

Comment: Haha glad to hear it :D I did a small change to the snack I linked to in my last comment to make it smoother by running them in parallell. The downside to this approach is that `useNativeDriver` doesn't support animating height :/

Comment: Yeah. Besides `onLayout` is not suggested when rendering multiple items! By the way that looks cool!

Comment: I found a nice way to handle it using onLayout on the wrapper, and using the height to animate translateY equivalent of the wrapper height. Works super and with good performance too. Thanks for the help!